# I would like to create a Setup.exe, that asks the user for a key, which is in a database. How is this possible?

Tags: installation, request, key, user-input, setup.exe

I have a already a Database full of keys and I have coded requests to communicate with the Database. My Question is, how can I create an Installer/Setup.exe File, where the User has to put in a Key and only if the key is correct the installer will continue otherwise the User is "trapped" on this page until the key is correct.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using c++ or c#